# Force a controlled rejection in promise.allSettled()

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I am trying to force a rejection for a `promise.allSettled()` function in a controlled way.
The idea is run a series of urls in batches through an API, this API from time to time returns a 500 error for a given request and it can be safetly retried. So I want to trigger a rejection on `promise.allSettled()` where I can collect the failing urls and later on rerun then on a recursion.

**Batchrequest function**

```
export async function batchRequest(poolLimit, array, iteratorFn, exception) {
  const promises = []
  const racers = new Set()

  for (const item of array) {
    const pro = Promise.resolve().then(() => iteratorFn(item, array))
    promises.push(pro)
    racers.add(pro)
    const clean = () => racers.delete(pro)
    pro.then(clean).catch(clean)

    if (racers.size >= poolLimit) await Promise.race(racers)
  }


  const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

  // Collect errors rejected by iteratorFn,
  const rejected = results
    .filter(({ status, reason }) => status === 'rejected' && reason.name === exception)
    .map(({ reason }) => reason.error)

  // Recurse the array of rejected urls
  if (rejected.length) {
    await batchRequest(poolLimit, rejected, iteratorFn, exception)
  }
}
```

Here we run the promises as normal but collect all rejected urls, I am trying to use the `exception` 'timeout' as the rule to determine if it needs to be rerun as it was just a timeout error.

**Iterator function**

```
async function runRequest(url) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios('https://exampleAPI.com')
    // Take the data and write it somewhere...
  
  } catch (error) {

    if (error.response.status === 500) {
      throw { name: 'timeout', url }
    }
  }
})

const urls = [...many urls]
await batchRequest(100, urls, runRequest, 'timeout')
```

I am getting an error saying

`This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason  "#<Object>".] { code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }`

How can I force a controlled rejection on `promise.allSettled()`?

**UPDATE**-----

I found that the unhandled rejection was at the point in which I started the batchrequest

```
await batchRequest(100, urls, runRequest, 'timeout')
```

It needs a try catch here:

```
const urls = [...many urls]
try {
  await batchRequest(100, urls, runRequest, 'timeout')
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

but the whole point was to use the `promise.allSettled()` to absorb the error and not get out of the batchrequest

Comment: "*I am getting an error saying I cannot throw inside a catch*" what is the *exact error*? Because [you most definitely can throw in a catch](https://jsbin.com/qomefiy/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: I get this `This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason ` and happends when it hits the `catch` block

Comment: That's does not say at all that you cannot throw inside a catch. It just says there is an unhandled promise rejection. So, find which one it is and handle it.

Comment: "*the whole point was to use the `Promise.allSettled()` to absorb the error*" - well, the error is thrown by `await Promise.race(racers)` before you even get to the `allSettled` call.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, to be honest the whole batchrequest it's from `https://github.com/rxaviers/async-pool` and was not really sure how it works, is it possible to get my idea to work with it?

Answer (score 1):

Just manually handle each promise and collect errors and results and return or throw when all promises resolved:

```js
const errors = [];
const results = [];

const promises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.reject("error1"),
  Promise.reject("error2"),
  Promise.resolve(3),
];

Promise.all(
  promises.map(p => p.then(r => results.push(r)).catch(e => errors.push(e)))
).then(() => {
  console.log({results, errors});
});
```

Comment: I am not collecting the results, I am writting to file so the promises do not return anything when successful

Comment: One nitpick: `Array.prototype.push` is not a bound method so cannot be passed as a callback. Replace e.g. `errors.push` with `errors.push.bind(errors)`.

Comment: @Code Spirit This does not take into account the fact that I want to control the rejections

Comment: @Álvaro Yes you can, you can chain the promises infinitely. I have just used a simple example but you can still add your own logic to handlers.

Comment: @CodeSpirit but `promise.all()` halts the requests when one fails, I want to carry on even when one fails

Comment: @Álvaro untrue, all the *individual* requests here have `.catch` handlers, so there will be no uncaught rejection to make the `Promise.all` reject: all requests will be made and either succeed or fail.

Comment: @JaredSmith Soi if I can use `promise.all()` how comes I cannot use `promise.allSettled()`

Comment: @Álvaro you can. Doesn't matter in this case: because every individual Promise from a request has a `.catch` handler the difference is pretty minimal.

Comment: But it does not work, the throw in the catch pushes the error on the first call, like I explain on the update so the batchrequest does not collect anything, it fails right there on the invocation

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're not handling the exception thrown by the `runRequest` or the first call to `iteratorFn`. That's what's causing the "unhandled exception" error.

I'd suggest to run this code through a debugger and go line by line until you find the line causing you to get that exception thrown.

Comment: I though that promise.allSettled() does that automatically by creating the object `{ status: 'rejected', reason: Error: an error }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: Your promises in this case aren't rejecting. They have an unhandled exception. I encourage you to run this through a debugger. I'm not entirely sure what the code in the ```for``` loop does as well since it's written obscurely. Your problem might lie there. But I'm 95% sure that you're not handling the errors properly.

Comment: You are right, it was the first call, the thing I do not understand it's why I can not deal with that from the `promise.allSettled()` rejection

Comment: ```Promise.allSettled``` is based on the ```Promise.reject``` and ```Promise.resolve``` functions. During an exception neither of those functions are called.  ```allSettled``` doesn't know how to work with that so you need to catch the exception being thrown from your ```runRequest``` function